# SSH.NET "Server string is null or empty" exception

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I use SSH.NET(2013.4.7 version) library for uploading files to SFTP server.
Here is piece of my code:

```
using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    ...
}
```

I get following error message on Connect() method execution:
*"System.InvalidOperationException: Server string is null or empty."*

I have found small advice regarding this issue here: http://www.ipbalance.com/programming/ms-powershell/1098-powershell-how-to-use-sshnet-library-for-cisco-on-windows-7.html
to use 'x.x.x.x' host format instead of x.x.x.x, but it doesn't help me.

Value of `host` variable is "153.112.49.198". `port` is 22.
It works fine, when I use FileZilla tool with the same host, port, username and password.

Stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Server string is null or empty.
at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
at [here is my method]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug that? What is the content of `host`?

Comment: @RenéVogt, the question is edited

Comment: Can you connect using command-line `ssh` or PuTTY? What are the other variables?

Comment: Show us an exception callstack + What version of the library are you using?

Comment: @Jakuje, yes I can connect via FileZilla.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, please, see stack trace above. Version is 2013.4.7

Comment: Try to login with PuTTY and show us its event log + Try to debug the `Session.Connect` and see if it reads any other `serverVersion` (`this.SocketReadLine(ref serverVersion)`) before it encounters the empty line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I have solved this problem. 
There was SFTP server setting “Max number of connections” with value “1” by default, so I was not able to connect, since FileZilla's connection was already created.